# php regex results in array to string conversion error

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to learn regex in php. Why does this result in an array to string conversion error on the last line and how do I fix it?

```
$document = "{title}this is the title{/title}";
preg_match("/{title}(.*){\/title}/", $document, $match);

echo $match;
```

Comment: `$match` is an array, use `print_r($match)`

Comment: Also, for learning purposes, a useful tool for playing around with regex and how it will work with PHP is http://www.phpliveregex.com

Answer (score 1):

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/H91beq):

```
$document = "{title}this is the title{/title}";
preg_match("/{title}(.*){\/title}/", $document, $match);
//echo $match; // PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/jxkaKh/prog.php on line 5
print_r($match);
// => Array(    [0] => {title}this is the title{/title}    [1] => this is the title)
```

See [`preg_match` reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> `int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )`
>   
> ...
>   `matches`
>   If `matches` is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. **`$matches[0]`** will contain the text that matched the full pattern, **`$matches[1]`** will have the text that matched the **first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on**.

And your pattern contains a capture group defined as `(.*)`.